# How to Delete a Page in the middle of Route stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Think I have Four pages in my app

```
Page1 
Page2
Page3
Page4
```

I Push pages like this

```
 Page1 => Page2 => Page3 => Page4
```

then when i am one `Page4` i want to push to `Page2` but i want `Page2` on the stack to be removed before pushing

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods of [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html) that can help you according to your specific need. Like

```
popAndPushNamed
popUntil
pushAndRemoveUntil
pushNamed
pushNamedAndRemoveUntil
pushReplacement
```

Comment: @Nagual do you think you can help me or point me to it?